# Renaming computer with loop

Tags: c#, loops

I am a bit new to c# and I have tried to find a way to look if a computer is found in the domain with a specific name. If that system exist the the program needs to add a number so that a new computer name is generated. Tried that with a loop, but have the feeling that I did not do it correctly. Thanks for the feedback.

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
int i = 1;
while (i < 100)

    try
    {
        // find the computer in question
        ComputerPrincipal computer = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "PC-" + userName + "-" + i);

        // if found - add an number
        if (computer != null)
        {
            bool done = SetComputerName("PC-" + userName + "-" + i++);

            if (done)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("We renamed your computer press ok to restart the computer");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            bool done = SetComputerName("PC-" + userName + "-1");
        }
```

Comment: You have a feeling? Did you get an error? What is your question?

Comment: `but have the feeling that I did not do it correctly` ... so it worked or it did not. What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a pretty serious logic error here.

If `COMPUTERNAME-1` exists, you'll set the name to `COMPUTERNAME-2`.  Even if that already exists.  Or you would be if you didn't have a bug that causes `i` not to increment until *after* making the new name.  In actuality, you're always trying to set the name to `COMPUTERNAME-1`.

Probably you should be looking for the first name that *isn't* used.  When a name is used, do nothing and let the loop increase `i` and keep looking.

(I haven't even considered problems associated with whether the computer is already a domain member, or race conditions if two computers try to claim the same name at the same time)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at it the wrong way. Logic thinking can be hard sometimes. :)